# What is a good data structure to represent an undirected graph?

Tags: data-structures, graph, structure, functor, sml

I need to construct an undirected graph.  I don't need it to do anything too fancy, but ideally it would work like this:

```
structure UDG = UndirectedGraph
val g = UDG.empty
val g = UDG.addEdges(g, n1, [n2, n4, n7]) (* n1 is connected to n2, n4, and n7 *)
val g = UDG.addEdge(g, n2, n3)
UDG.connected(g, n2) (* returns [n1, n3] *)
```

Is there a good data structure in SML/NJ to model these relationships?  Should I just roll my own?

## Updates

I've gone ahead and tried rolling my own, but I get a type mismatch error when I try to test it.  My experience with SML structures and functors is pretty basic, so I think I'm doing something obviously wrong.  How do I get this to work?  Also, can you help me make this an `'a graph`?  That seems to make more sense, semantically.

### Code

```
signature ORD_NODE =
sig
  type node
  val compare : node * node -> order
  val format : node -> string
end

signature GRAPH =
sig
  structure Node : ORD_NODE
  type graph
  val empty : graph

  (* val addEdge : graph * Node.node * Node.node -> graph
  *  addEdge (g, x, y) => g with an edge added from x to y. *)
  val addEdge : graph * Node.node * Node.node -> graph

  val format : graph -> string
end

functor UndirectedGraphFn (Node : ORD_NODE) :> GRAPH =
struct
  structure Node = Node
  structure Key = struct
    type ord_key = Node.node
    val compare = Node.compare
  end
  structure Map = BinaryMapFn(Key)

  type graph = Node.node list Map.map (* Adjacency list *)
  val empty = Map.empty

  fun addEdge (g, x, y) = (* snip *)   
  fun format g = (* snip *)
end

structure UDG = UndirectedGraphFn(struct
  type node = int
  val compare = Int.compare
  val format = Int.toString
end)
```

### Error

When I do

```
structure UDG = UndirectedGraphFn(struct
  type node = int
  val compare = Int.compare
  val format = Int.toString
end)

UDG.addEdge (UDG.empty,1,2)
```

I get a type mismatch:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [literal]
  operator domain: UDG.graph * ?.UDG.node * ?.UDG.node
  operand:         UDG.graph * int * int
  in expression:
    UDG.addEdge (UDG.empty,1,2)
```

Comment: hmm in your error message, it says 'UDG.addEdge (UDG.empty.....

perhaps its trying to multiply the string 'empty' by UDG.node? sorry not familiar with SML

Answer (score 4):

There are several possibilities with differing pros and cons suited to different operations on the graphs.
[This nice intro](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/mfourman/teaching/mlCourse/notes/L13.pdf) gives background and examples of using Adjacency Lists and Adjacency Matrices.

Using them in an undirected fashion involves trade offs (space verses speed). [this course material](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2004fa/lectures/lecture14.htm) goes into more detail on the adjacency list style and provides some thoughts on the possible alterations for use in undirected usage.

Comment: would the -1 care to give an indication as to why?

Comment: I'm sorry but I voted down your answer so it wouldn't get auto-accepted.  Not that it isn't helpful, it's just that it I don't think it (or the other answers) deserve to be accepted yet.  If you go ahead and edit it I will retract my -1.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't have much to offer on your error message I'm afraid, SML isn't my forte though I would ask why you rolled your own over using the ones supplied in the linked paper...

Comment: I feel like an ass for not looking at your links; I just assumed they were the standard adjacency list vs matrix stuff.  Even though they're not exactly what I was looking for, they were still helpful.

Answer (score 4):

OK I'm not familiar with this language (please pardon my ignorance):

I'd simply use the following structure:

```
V.E1.E2.En+1
V2.E1.E2.En+1
Vn+1.E1.E2.En+1
```

so basically the first digit before the decimal would represent the Vertice, and each Edge would be represented followed by a decimal point (kind of like an IP address)

such that:

[image]

could be stored as:

1.2.5

2.1.5.3

3.2.4

4.3.5.6

5.1.2.4

6.4

Then in your code, its simple to add/delete edges, and very easy to parse (because the vertice is always the first number)

Comment: This is actually a pretty nifty idea. Especially if the data structure is to be filled first, and then used for visualization purposes. I'm doing a hobby project that aims to create such a visualization and I'll definitely try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

A really easy one would be a hashtable, with the key as the source node, and the value as a list of connecting nodes. Then write an add function that does two hashtable insertions, one as (src, tgt), the other as (tgt, src).

In ocaml:

```
let add n1 n2 =
  let aux n1 n2 =
    match Hashtbl.find_option tbl n1 with
    | None -> Hashtbl.add tbl n1 [n2]
    | Some nodes -> Hashtbl.replace tbl n1 (n2::nodes)
  in
  let _ = aux n1 n2 in
  aux n2 n1
```

This would be a directed graph, it's just you would add both directions on insert. The hashtable lookup function will act as your `connected` function.

(Actually, in Ocaml hashtables offer multiple values for a key, so you could just use the `Hashtbl.find_all` function and save the list. But this is the easiest to translate into SML.)

Answer (score 1):

[image: a graph and its adjacency list]

We can represent a graph as a list of lists,we call this datastructure: an adjacency list
.